# How do i utilize the now() function in mysql when creating a stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am being asked to create a table which i did with this command:.

```
CREATE TABLE log ( NoEmp, NoDept, LocReg1, LocReg2, LocReg3, TotSales, AvgSale, AvgSaleMo, AvgSaleYr, logdate );
```

Now i need to create a Stored Procedure to populate the log table as follows:

```
First column—Number of Employees
Second column— Number of Departments
Third column – Number of locations in Region 1
Fourth column – Number of locations in Region 2
Five column – Number of locations in Region 3
Sixth column – Total Sales amount
Seventh column—Average Sale
Eight column – Average Sales Per Month
Ninth column – Average Sales per Year
Tenth column – Date and time when the row was inserted  Hint: Use now() to insert system date.
```

This is  the code that i used to create a stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE populatelog()
BEGIN 

SELECT COUNT(NoEmp), COUNT(NoDept), COUNT(LocReg1), COUNT(LocReg2), COUNT(LocReg3), 
SUM(TotSales), AVG(AvgSale), AVG(AvgSaleMo), AVG(AvgSaleYr), 
VALUES(logdate, now()) FROM log;

END//

DELIMITER;

 CALL populatelog();
```

I keep getting an error :"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' now()) FROM log;"

I don't know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: *I don't know what i am doing wrong?* See [VALUES() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_values) description. 1) It has one argument only 2) It makes sense in `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` only.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense. I am sorry i am new to mysql and programming in general, is there a good tutorial to do this??

Comment: I have already given a link to the function description in Reference Manual. It is the best tutorial.

Comment: Explain what idea is embedded in the expression `VALUES(logdate, now())`?